# Disable HTML5 video autoplay only on smartphone

Tags: css, html, video, mobile, smartphone

I have a full-width video background on a website with the autoplay attribute. It works fine.

On the smartphone device however, I don't want to display this video.
So I use the css : display:none;

But the video is still downloaded by firefox on smartphone...
The video does not appear but it is still downloaded in cache...

How can I fix that? Is there a solution to disable the autoplay on the little screen and keep it on the larger device?

Comment: check if the screen is a certain size and remove `autoplay` as its an attribute that if exists it will auto play

Comment: Yes but I would like to keep autoplay on computer

Comment: Thats why you check screen size, if its desktop size, keep autoplay, if it isnt remove it.

Comment: Yes. That is my question : How to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML

```
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var screenWidth = $(window).width();
  // if window width is smaller than 800 remove the autoplay attribute
  // from the video
  if (screenWidth < 800){
        $('video').removeAttr('autoplay');
  } else {
    $('video').attr('autoplay');
  }
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rowj0sae/

Comment: Thank you very much Hipady ! You just saved me ! Works fine !